# Generator is not working in prolog DCG. How do we change arguments in prolog function so that it starts working as a generator

Tags: parsing, prolog, arguments, dcg

This is my code that works as recognizer. This works.

```
s --> v(X), v(X), c(Y).
s --> v(X), c(Y), c(X).

v(quiet) --> line(quiet).
v(loud) --> line(loud).

c(quiet) --> line(quiet).
c(loud)  --> line(loud).

line(quiet) --> ['laa!'].
line(loud)  --> ['LAA!'].
```

But then I am trying to work this code for a parser

```
s(s(X,X,Y)) --> v(X), v(X), c(Y).
s(s(X,Y,X)) --> v(X), c(Y), c(X).

v(quiet,v(quiet)) --> line(quiet).
v(loud, v(loud)) --> line(loud).

c(quiet, c(quiet)) --> line(quiet).
c(loud, c(loud))  --> line(loud).

line(quiet, line('laa!')) --> ['laa!'].
line(loud , line('LAA!')) --> ['LAA!'].
```

I am not sure what is the right ways to change arguments so that the recognizer works as a parser as well. Can anyone guide me how do we change arguments so it works as a parser.

Comment: One obvious problem is that your number of arguments isn't consistent. So you call `v(X)` but you define `v(quiet, v(quiet))` which will not unify with `v(X)`. So any call to `v(X)` will fail. Likewise, `c(X)`. Why do you have those extra arguments? Just keep it simple and use your original code for `v(quiet) -->...` etc. You could also write, `s(X, Y) --> v(X), v(X), c(Y).` etc, but I'm not sure what your use case is for needing `s(s(X, X, Y)) -->...`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were already 90% of the way there with your original code. I don't know what you want to parse to, so I came up with this:

```
s(xxy(X,Y)) --> v(X), v(X), c(Y).
s(xyx(X,Y)) --> v(X), c(Y), c(X).

v(quiet) --> line(quiet).
v(loud) --> line(loud).

c(quiet) --> line(quiet).
c(loud)  --> line(loud).

line(quiet) --> ['laa!'].
line(loud)  --> ['LAA!'].
```

As you can see, the only material change here is changing `s//0` to `s//1` and returning something with the X and Y variables (which were previously singletons anyway). An example of using it to parse all your sentences is:

```
?- phrase(s(Parse), Sentence).
Parse = xxy(quiet, quiet),
Sentence = ['laa!', 'laa!', 'laa!'] ;
Parse = xxy(quiet, loud),
Sentence = ['laa!', 'laa!', 'LAA!'] ;
Parse = xxy(loud, quiet),
Sentence = ['LAA!', 'LAA!', 'laa!'] ;
Parse = xxy(loud, loud),
Sentence = ['LAA!', 'LAA!', 'LAA!'] ;
Parse = xyx(quiet, quiet),
Sentence = ['laa!', 'laa!', 'laa!'] ;
Parse = xyx(quiet, loud),
Sentence = ['laa!', 'LAA!', 'laa!'] ;
Parse = xyx(loud, quiet),
Sentence = ['LAA!', 'laa!', 'LAA!'] ;
Parse = xyx(loud, loud),
Sentence = ['LAA!', 'LAA!', 'LAA!'].
```

To give you more help I'd probably have to know more about the intermediate representation you want to obtain, but hopefully this will illustrate the idea. You were so close already!